# Python: Selection Sort

Tags: python

I would like to convert the following JAVA code to python (am a beginner in Python)

```
public void selectionSort(int[] arr) {
      int i, j, minIndex, tmp;
      int n = arr.length;
      for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            minIndex = i;
            for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
                  if (arr[j] < arr[minIndex])
                        minIndex = j;
            if (minIndex != i) {
                  tmp = arr[i];
                  arr[i] = arr[minIndex];
                  arr[minIndex] = tmp;
            }
      }
}
```

This is what I wrote but it doesn't work and I cannot figure out what am I doing wrongly

```
A = [86, 2,4 ,5, 6122, 87]

def selectionSort(a):
    n = len(a)
    print ("n = ", n)
    for i in range (0, n-1):
        minIndex = i
        j = i+1
        for j in range (0, n):
            if(a[j] < a[minIndex]):
                minIndex = j
        if minIndex != i:
            tmp = a[i]
            a[i] = a[minIndex]
            a[minIndex] = tmp



selectionSort(A)
print(A)
```

Please help me understand why

Comment: Why? Python ain't java. Use `A.sort()`

Comment: What is `j = i + 1` supposed to be for? Immediately after you assign it, you rewrite it with 0.

Comment: @Fredrik If the OP is learning to program and learning python it may be a good exercise.

Comment: @Bakuriu - I'm just saying that learning python in a pythonic way is superior to learning python by mimicking java...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for j in range (0, n)
```

is not the same as in Java, where you use i+1 to start.

A more pythonic way to implement selection sort could look like this:

```
A = [86, 2,4 ,5, 6122, 87]
def selectionSort(a):
    # Go through all positions except the last one 
    # (that one will automatically be correct)
    for index in range(len(a)-1):
        value = a[index]
        # enumerate all (index, value) pairs from the rest of the list 
        # and take the pair with the smallest value
        min_subindex, min_value = min(enumerate(a[index+1:]), key=lambda x: x[1])
        if min_value < value:
            a[index] = min_value
            a[min_subindex + index + 1] = value

selectionSort(A)
print(A) # [2, 4, 5, 86, 87, 6122]
```

Comment: enumerate forms a list of tuples but why does it take a[index+1]: as an argument ?

Comment: `some_list[x:y:z]` is list slicing, explained in [this StackOverflow Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation). The idea is to only enumerate the rest of the list.

Comment: min_subindex will have the same value as min_value ?

Comment: I ran the code and I knew that min_subindex will give the index of the min_value .. so basically min_subindex is the first value of the tuple

Comment: @HayaRaed yes, `a, b = some_tuple` will put `some_tuple[0]` into `a` and `some_tuple[1]` into b. It also works for more than just two values.

Answer (score 2):

Change the two lines

```
j = i+1
for j in range (0, n):
```

to

```
for j in range (i+1, n):
```

to match

```
for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
```

other nitpicks

swapping in python is elegantly done as

```
a[i], a[minIndex] = a[minIndex], a[i]
```

and the entire block

```
    minIndex = i
    for j in range (i+1, n):
        if(a[j] < a[minIndex]):
            minIndex = j
    if minIndex != i:
        a[i], a[minIndex] = a[minIndex], a[i]
```

can be refactored as

```
    minIndex = min(range(i,n), key = partial(getitem, a))
    a[i], a[minIndex] = a[minIndex], a[i]
```

provided you import [partial from functools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) and [getitem from operator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.getitem)

```
from functools import partial
from operator import getitem
```

So your final version would look something like

```
from functools import partial
from operator import getitem
def selectionSort(a):
    n = len(a)
    for i in range (n-1):
        minIndex = min(range(i,n), key = partial(getitem, a))
        a[i], a[minIndex] = a[minIndex], a[i]
```

**seeing which at the end would make you wonder if converting Java Code to Python as an exercise was indeed a good way to learn Python**

Comment: Your final version is incorrect, since you swap unconditionally. I get `[2, 4, 5, 87, 86, 6122]` with your code

Comment: @mensi: On the contrary, the swap may be unconditional but the problem was with the index to the range, it should had been `i` instead of `i+1`

Answer (score 0):

Issues:

1. When you do `j in range(0, n-1)` it will start the loop at `0` instead of `i+1`.

Use

```
for j in range(i+1, n-1)
```

Working code:

```
A = [86, 2,4 ,5, 6122, 87]

def selectionSort(a):
    n = len(a)
    print ("n = ", n)
    for i in range (0, n-1):
        minIndex = i
        for j in range (i+1, n):
            if(a[j] < a[minIndex]):
                minIndex = j

        if minIndex != i:
            a[i], a[minIndex] = a[minIndex], a[i]

selectionSort(A)
print(A)
```

Comment: Thank You SO MUCHHH!!!! you were right , it started looping at 0 and everything got messed up